# Generate the histogram of an object while ignoring the background

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, opencv, octave

The calculation of an image histogram is a simple task, and most of the available languages or libraries provide functions for this purpose. But if I wanted to exclude the image background from the calculation of the histogram (assuming for example to have a mask to crop the object contained in the image), are there functions that allow you to calculate the histogram considering only the portion of the image defined by a mask?

**UPDATE.** The mask does not have a particular shape, since it is obtained by subtracting the background: in other words, the black pixels of the mask identify the background, while the white pixels identify the object.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't have a particular shape? It should have the same size of the image, with a value of true in the background pixels. Can you give an example (read, show us the code).

Comment: @carandraug _what do you mean it doesn't have a particular shape?_ Sorry, I have probably wrong with using the adjective "particular": the mask does not have a specific shape (it is not a square mask, nor rectangular, etc.); for example, if I have an image containing a cup of coffee, I would only calculate the histogram of the cup and exclude background pixels.

Comment: then your question is not about getting the histogram. Your question is how you identify the background which is a very very different question.

Comment: @carandraug: my question is not _how identify the background_ (because I have already identified the background), but I would like to calculate the histogram of the object.

Comment: then show me how you identified it. Because the answer to your question is dependent on how you identify your background.

Comment: @carandraug: I have the an image containing the background, so I used [this source code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/467-image-background-removal) in order to make a mask.

Comment: that code does return a logical matrix with exactly the same size as the input image. You can use it for [logical indexing](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Logical-Values.html). Doing `image(mask)` will return the pixel values of `image` where `mask` is true. That said, the answer by @Mr E is correct. However, since you are doing image processing, do not use `hist`, use `imhist` instead. You'll need the image package (get version 2.0.0 which fixed a big bug on it).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159493/how-to-recognize-histograms-with-a-specific-shape-in-opencv-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does

```
hist(im(mask))
```

or depending on which way round your mask is defined

```
hist(im(~mask))
```

work?

Comment: The mask does not have a particular shape, since it is obtained by subtracting the background: in other words, the black pixels of the mask identify the background, while the white pixels identify the object. Consequently, the command `im(mask)` will not work.

Comment: If the mask has the same shape along the first two dimensions as the image, it should work. Doesn't your mask have that property?

Comment: You're right. I ran the command `im(mask)`, which returns a vector: the length of this vector is equal to the product between the number of rows and number of columns of the image. However, I have a color image, so should I create an _m-by-n-by-3_ matrix containing `mask` at each channel?